# How to get char type in 2d array to set start position

Tags: c#, arrays, switch-statement, maze

I'm tring to implement switch that would asset block types based on char, but for some reason it's still throwing compilation error.

```
            var width = widths[0];
            var height = loaded.Length;
            var map = new char[height, width];

            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                {
                    map[i, j] = loaded[i][j];

                    switch (char)
                    {
                        case '#': map[i, j] = Maze.CHAR_WALL; break;
                        case 'S': map[i, j] = Maze.CHAR_START; break;
                        case 'F': map[i, j] = Maze.CHAR_FINISH; break; 
                    }

                }
            }
            return new Maze(map);
```

And how could I get the X and Y of the start? So I can input it here.
Note that I know that GetNextPosition is a mess, but that's a completely different story.

```
private int _angle;

    public DwarfLeft(Maze m) : base(m.StartX, m.StartY)
    {
        //Entry validation
        _angle = m.StartAngle;
        // Start X, Y
    }

    public override bool GetNextPosition(out int nx, out int ny)
    { 
        // "return" new position based on _angle and X,Y
        // wall-following
        ny = Y;
        nx = X+1;

        if (_angle < 90)
        {
            ny += 1;
        }
        else if (_angle == 90)
        {
            nx -= 1;
        }
        else if (_angle == 180)
        {
            ny -= 1;
        }

        else nx += 1;

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: "switch (char)" ?

Comment: No, that made it worser, I'm using switch(condition) like this all the time, I'm not sure why it's yelling at me.

Comment: I rewrote the switch to  switch(map[i, j])  and I think it should do the trick, but I still don't know how to get the X, Y of the start position